# How to sort NSMutable array in ascending order

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray

How to sort NSMutable array in ascending order. Can any one help me out this.

Answer (score 4):

You haven't said what's in your array, but if it's something that responds to `-compare:` then you can use

```
[myArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare):];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to sort an array of object

```
    NSSortDescriptor * descFirstname = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstname" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor * descLastname = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastname" ascending:YES];
[myArrayOfPerson sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descLastname,descFirstname, nil]];
    [descFirstname release];
    [descLastname release];
```

Comment: Don't forgot to (auto)release the objects.

Comment: @DarkDust Of course! I forgot it but correct the sample code ;) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a [NSSortDescriptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html), have a look at [Sort Descriptor Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SortDescriptors/Concepts/Creating.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil
ascending:YES] autorelease];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [sortValuesArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSLog(@"sortedArray%@",sortedArray);
```

sortValuesArray is the array that you want to sort.

Comment: You didn't even specify a key.

Comment: I have done this code with sorting array which contain numbers so there were no key and mostly the arrays dont have key that why.But no matters It's good that you got the solution ....happy coding...:)